# Parsing JSON fails with not a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse the following JSON in Java program.

**JSON**

```
{
    "data": {
        "pageIDentifier":" nametitle",
        "page": {
            "pageID”:” sports_league_member",
            "platform":" www",
            "activityType":" ent",
            "businessUnit":" ent",
            "productLOB":" ent",
            "productOffered":" abc",
            "productQualifier”:” abc:a bc”,
            "flowType”:” sports_com”,
            "pageDesc”:” desc”,
            "attributes": {
                "pageType":" www",
                "host”:” finaluser”,
                "appId”:” SportsAppID_user”,
                "daEnvironment”:” releaser”,
                "jvm":" ent_logon_01",
                "xCKey":" SportsAppID_user",
                "daUID":" jddc9yu5pi1yy6",
                "sysEnv”:” user”,
                "uri”:” /www/sportscenter”,
                "daPageName":" "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JAVA Program**

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("test.json");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
String jsonData = readFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(jobj.getJSONArray("data").toString());
System.out.println("jarr: " + jarr);
```

I am getting the following error when executing this code. Please note, *jsonData* is giving the entire json string without any issue.

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["data"] is not a JSONArray.

How can i parse "data" value from the above json value? Please advise.

Comment: your JSON example clearly shows that **data is not an array!**

Comment: @JonnathanQ is right, data it not an array, if it is an array you should read it by `jobj.getJSONArray("data")` without doing `new JSONArray`

Comment: Also you have some not regular double quotes but 'inclined' ones

Comment: @JoseDaSilva: that's probably an artifact of using some MS program(s) while posting -- MS likes to change quote marks and calls this 'smart quotes'. If the real data had those invalid chars JSONObject would barf _before_ reaching the `.getJSONArray` call.

Comment: JSON arrays begin with [ and end with ]. For example [1,2,3,4]. The value associated with `data` is a JSON object since it begins with { and ends with }. See http://json.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is not an array

Try this :

```
System.out.println("jarr: " + jobj.getJSONObject("data").toString());
```